# How can I insert a 'with' statement under a condition?

Tags: python, with-statement

I have a piece of code structured this way:

```
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
    use_tqdm = True
except ImportError:
    use_tqdm = False


if use_tqdm:
    with tqdm(total=5) as pbar:
        # --- many nested for loops ---
        pbar.update(1)
else:
    # --- identical nested for loops, without pbar.update(1) ---
```

How can I avoid repeating said long block of code?

I cannot put the condition only on the single pbar line inside because what `tqdm` does is create a progress bar, so it needs to be instantiated only once.

I think I'm looking for a way to tell Python "hey, consider the with statement only if `use_tqdm = True`, otherwise pretend it never existed", but any other suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks!

(tqdm package: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm )

Comment: Create a dummy "tqdm" class which creates a dummy "pbar" on "with" which does nothing when "pbar.update" is called.

Comment: You should never write `if use_tqdm = True:` or even the corrected `if use_tqdm == True:`. Just write `if use_tqdm:`.

Comment: Define and call a function with the code in it?

Comment: You don't even need the flag. Define an API-compatible `tqdm` dummy class in the `except ImportError`; then there is no need to write two different pieces of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
except ImportError:
    class tqdm:
        def __int__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            pass

        def __enter__(self):
            class Dummy:
                def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    pass

            return Dummy()

        def __exit__(self, *args):
            pass

with tqdm(total = 5) as pbar:
   --- many nested for loops ---
            pbar.update(1)
```

If the import fails, you just get a dummy context and an object whose `update` method is a no-op. No separate code is needed.

Comment: I think it needs to be *def update(self, n=1):* for full compliance with the tqdm documentation. Although OP doesn't rely on this, if he changes his code to *pbar.update(n=1)* that would work with the real tqdm but not with this dummy class. Of course, defining the dummy class within the exception handler makes more sense than my Answer which I will now delete

Comment: Fixed. I'm not all that familiar with `tqdm` myself, so I leave it as an exercise to make the dummy more compliant (e.g., rejecting arguments that `tqdm` would reject, etc) if that's desired for testing code that uses the dummy.

Comment: This could be made shorter with `@contextlib.contextmanager`, or if `__enter__` returned `self`.

Comment: @user3840170 True, I'm not sure why I didn't just define `update` on `tqdm` instead of simulating (what I presumed was) a second class.

Answer (score 0):

So there's two separate problems here:

- replicated but very similar code
- conditional allocation of resources

For the first one define a function that optionally takes a `pbar` and defaults to something that signals "ignore me". As @Michael-Butscher suggested either create a dummy class that just has a `pass` in all functions you wish to ignore or, a bit more dirty, just guard ever occurrence with an `if`. Example:

```py
class PbarDummy:
    def update(self, _):
        pass

def many_for_loops(pbar=PbarDummy()):
   --- many nested for loops ---
      pbar.update(1)
```

This then also solves your second problem, as you can conditionally call the function inside the `with` block or not.

```
if use_tqdm:
   with tqdm(total = 5) as pbar:
      many_for_loops(pbar=pbar)
else:
   many_for_loops()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for that nested for loops with input of pbar. Inside that function, you check if the pbar passed in is None meaning not to update progress bar, otherwise use it and call update:

```
try:
    from tqdm import tqdm
    use_tqdm = True
except ImportError:
    use_tqdm = False

def process_nested_for_loops(pbar):
    # --- many nested for loops ---
        if pbar is not None:
            pbar.update(1)


if use_tqdm = True:
   with tqdm(total = 5) as pbar:
       process_nested_for_loops(pbar)
else:
   process_nested_for_loops(None)
```